# How to update xmltype in PLSQL without altering empty tags into null tags

Tags: plsql

I need to update an XML field and within the XML field there is an empty tag. The tag must remain empty as it cannot be NULL as defined in XSD. When using updatexml or xmlquery modify, PLSQL changes the empty tag  into a null tag . Is there any way to prevent/avoid this?

```sql
SELECT
    to_char(UPDATEXML(
        XMLTYPE('<root>
                   <empty></empty>
                   <notempty>value</notempty>
                 </root>'), 'root/notempty/text()', 'value1').getclobval())
FROM dual
```

With the previous query I get the following result:

`<root><empty/><notempty>value1</notempty></root>`

While I'm looking for the following result:

`<root><empty></empty><notempty>value1</notempty></root>`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNxLq.png)